# establish connection between python script to powerbi dashboard , want to load exportable view from powerbi table visual to python script

Tags: python, powerbi

establish connection between python script to powerbi dashboard , want to load exportable view from powerbi table visual to python script using python code, need steps of connectivity between powerbi and python using workspace id and report id

```
from msal import PublicClientApplication
from powerbiclient import Report

# Replace 'your_client_id' with your Power BI application's client ID
client_id = 'your_client_id'
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'

# Configure the application for interactive authentication
app = PublicClientApplication(client_id=client_id, authority=authority)

# Acquire a token interactively
accounts = app.get_accounts()
if accounts:
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'], account=accounts[0])
else:
    result = app.acquire_token_interactive(['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'])

# Check if the token was successfully acquired
if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']
else:
    raise Exception('Failed to acquire access token.')# Get the report
report = Report(workspace_id='your_workspace_id', report_id='your_report_id', auth=access_token)

# Refresh the report to fetch the latest data (optional)
report.refresh()

# Get the table data from the report
table_data = report.export_to_file('Table1', 'Excel', 'table_view_export.xlsx', include_paginated_table_export=True)
```